# How to stop fractions from simplifying, when inside a Manipulate[]

Tags: manipulate, output-formatting

I want to stop this fraction from simplifying inside a `Manipulate[]`

```
Manipulate[
           x/y
           , {x, 7, 10, 1}
           , {y, 7, 10, 1}
]
```

i.e. when this program is evaluated the fraction should look like:

$$\frac{7}{7}$$

---

I have tried many different wrapping configurations of `ToString`, `Hold`, `HoldForm`:

but to no avail:

[image]

Surprisingly mathematica will even simplify a fraction containing strings to $1$

Comment: If the linked question does not suit your needs, edit your question to explain why.

Comment: Thanks, the solution of `Internal\`RationalNoReduce[x, y]` in the linked question works great. I read several questions before I posted my question, but for some reason I never found that link :(

Comment: Yes, I could see why. I had made a few changes to it so that other people who get in your situation will not encounter the same trouble.